# are session variables in php confidential

Tags: php, session

suppose if I where to store the query of a url using `$_GET['query']` and finally convert into a session variable `$_SESSION['var']` and post it on webpage  if  I have different queries will different people see same or different query? Also if the same person is using different queries will he say the same or different one?

Comment: *post it on webpage if I have different queries will different people see same or different query* -- I'm confused. Could you explain?

Comment: What you mean by confidential.?Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: using echo $_SESSION['query']

Comment: confidential mean are they replenished every time on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you store in `$_SESSION` is specific to that session and nothing in `$_SESSION` is directly accessible to any user, it is only accessible if you make it accessible, for instance with an `echo`. **However**, sessions are identified by a *session identifier* (also called an *sid*) which is passed back and forth between the server and the user (usually in a cookie, sometimes in the query string in the URL).

*Session hijacking* occurs when someone other than the person who initiated the session gets a hold of the sid and is then able to make a request using the same session. In this case, they will have access to anything that the legitimate user has access to. So in this case, **no** they are not confidential. There are lots of ways to protect against session hijacking, the best being to use secure connections (HTTPS). But that's a different question.

What a person sees depends on how you're presenting it. Showing us some sample code would help clarify things. For instance, if you do:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["query"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["query"];
}
$_SESSION["query"] = $_GET["query"];
?>
```

Then the user will always see the query they sent with the *last* request.

Honestly, it sounds like you're a little confused over what what a query is and what a session is. If you can clarify what you're *trying* to do, and especially if you can provide some sample code, we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are specific to individual users. When starting a session using `session_start()`, a random id is created and stored in a cookie in the user's browser. When this cookie is received in subsequent requests, that session is resumed when calling `session_start()`. Whatever you save in `$_SESSION` is saved in that session with that unique id, which is unique to the user who holds that cookie.

Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are significantly safer than, say, cookies. But it is still possible to steal a session and thus the hacker will have total access to whatever is in that session. Some ways to avoid this are IP Checking (which works pretty well, but is very low fi and thus not reliable on its own), and using a nonce. Typically with a nonce, you have a per-page "token" so that each page checks that the last page's nonce matches what it has stored.

If you want to dive in deeper. Go **[here](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html)**.